# Latex subections inside figure - toc shows subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I try to put a lot of these elements inside my thesis:

```
\subsection{Maschine}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=gray!10,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,9)
{\begin{center}\textbf{Factory}\end{center}};
\node[fill=white,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,8)
{String bestehend aus beliebig vielen Komponenten};
\node[fill=white,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,7)
{\texttt{<Factory> Komponenten </Factory>}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
Description
\end{figure}
```

I want to have them fixed. So I wrote a figure tag around the subsection.

Before this code I used the next line to prevent, that these subsections are shown in the table of content:

```
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
```

But they are shown, because of the figure tag around the subsections.

Is there a way to prevent latex from putting them into the toc or keep the subsections together without the figure tag?

Comment: It would be better to provide a complete MWE, and not just some part of your code. It would be easier for us to test the code.

Comment: Thats a problem, because its my bachelor thesis and I'm not allowed to show it here. But I think with this example, you can reproduce the problem. You have the subsection in the toc, because of the figure tag. And I don't want the subsection in the toc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), currently you just *describe* what code you use (figure tag). And wWhat do you mean by "I want to have them fixed."?

Comment: They should stick together. A drawing, with a description and a headline should stick together. Not seperated by a page break or the float mechanism.

Comment: If you don't want it to float, remove the `figure` environment and just stick with the `center` environment

Comment: For that probably is better to use the `titlesec` package, and when redefining the section do it inside a `minipage`. And as @cmhughes said, dont use the `figure` environment.

Comment: I can't put a subsection and the tikzpicture inside the minipage.

Comment: @cmhughes: But center doesn't help to stick the different elements together.

Comment: You could remove the `figure` environment, and stick the whole block in a `minipage` or other non-breaking box, such as `parbox`, `vbox`... the page-breaking consequences could be disastrous though...

Comment: As it stands I feel this is a far-from-clear question. There are no (sub)sections in the excerpt, and the comments suggest to me we need a broader description of the underlying problem.